# What theorems or frameworks explain why the roots of well-behaved functions $h : \mathbb{R} \leftarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ seem to be made up of "pieces"?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, analytic-geometry

First, some terminology: given functions $g,f:Y \leftarrow X$, the *equalizer* of $g$ and $f$ is defined to be the set of all solutions $x \in X$ to the equation $g(x)=f(x)$ in $Y$. Okay. The following seems to be a general phenomenon: given any two sufficiently well-behaved functions $g,f : \mathbb{R} \leftarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ with $g$ distinct from $f$, it tends to be the case that the equalizer of $g$ and $f$ can be broken up into discrete "parts" in a natural way, such that each part can be parametrized by a well-behaved function $\mathbb{R}^2 \leftarrow \mathbb{R}$. For example, if I type $$xe^y = y \cos(x)$$
into Wolfram Alpha, I get...

[image]

...which looks like it can be broken up into subsets that can each be viewed as parametrized by $\mathbb{R}$ via a smooth function.

Similarly, if I type $$xe^y = ye^x,$$ I get...

[image]

...which (once again) looks like distinct pieces, each of which can be parametrized by $\mathbb{R}$.

Now the equalizer of $g$ and $f$ just the equalizer of $g-f$ and $0$, or in other words the set of zeros of $g-f$. So we can simplify the question by thinking about the zeros of functions.

> **Question.** What frameworks and/or theorems are available to make sense of this phenomenon whereby for all sufficiently well-behaved
>   functions $h : \mathbb{R} \leftarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ distinct from the
>   zero function $0 : \mathbb{R} \leftarrow \mathbb{R}^2$, we find that
>   the roots of $h$ can be broken up into pieces, each of which can be parametrized by $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Functions are generically regular (have $df_x$ surjective) as long as the dimensions make that possible. So it's no surprise most points in the zero set should look like a manifold.

Comment: @MikeMiller, but regularity clearly isn't necessary for this phenomenon; look at the second graph for example, this isn't a submanifold, but its still clearly made of (two) pieces.

Comment: I said at most points, not all. At the critical point, your critical point is still non-degenerate, which is all you need for it to be the zero set of $x_1^2=x_2^2$ in a chart (the Morse lemma). As you let higher derivatives be bad (eg degenerate critical points), you should still get local statements like this, they'll just keep getting more complicated.

Comment: @goblin: Nevertheless, I'd still say that the implicit function theorem is exactly the mathematics that captures the intuition that making $m$ restrictions on $m+n$ "dimensions" produces level sets having "dimension" $n$.

Comment: @ZevChonoles, I don't think that captures what's going on here. The implicit function theorem only tells you about local behavior, and the requirements on the function of interest are pretty weak (e.g. continuous differentiable.) Here, something quite different is happening; the zeros of $h$ break up canonically, in a *global* way, into $1$-dimensional pieces. There appears to be nothing arbitrary or local about this decomposition; its unique, and its global; I don't get to choose it, *nature* choose it. And presumably, we need much more stringent assumptions on $h$ to ensure its existence.

Comment: You get something global by patching together the local data. All you need to do so is have the critical points in the zero set locally look like a union of lines.

Comment: @MikeMiller, what theorems or frameworks guarantee that the critical points have this property?

Comment: You get this when your critical points are nondegenerate - then it's precisely two lines. Maybe you can say $n$ lines if the $n$th derivative is nonzero but all smaller ones are zero - I've never really thought about critical points with "higher" nondegeneracies than the 2nd deriv (Morse fctns).

Comment: @MikeMiller, okay. I'll need to chew on that for awhile.

Comment: Sard's theorem addresses this to some extent, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sard's_theorem

Comment: @NickAlger, not really. That's just saying that there aren't many critical values. My interest is in the fact that even when there are critical values, nonetheless some kind of global decomposition obviously continues to exist in many cases.