# Reference request: are levelsets/levelspaces (as defined here) used anywhere in mathematics?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, algebraic-geometry, reference-request, optimization

Thinking about [unimodal distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unimodality) in multiple dimensions, I came up with the following.

Given a function $f : Y \leftarrow X$ where $X$ is a topological space, define that a *levelset* of $f$ is a subset $A$ of $X$ such that there exists $y \in Y$ such that $A$ is a connected component of $f^{-1}(y)$. Note that this differs somewhat from what appears to be the [usual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_set) definition. By the *levelspace*, let us mean the collection of all level sets. Write $\mathrm{lev}_f$ for the levelspace of $f$. So $\mathrm{lev}_f$ is a partitioning of $X$. We get a (set-theoretic) factorization of $f$ as the composite of two functions,

$$f_1 : Y \leftarrow \mathrm{lev}_f, \mbox{ and } f_0 : \mathrm{lev}_f \leftarrow X.$$

Anyway, returning to the opening sentence, I had this idea that maybe we should define:

> **Definition.** Given a function $f : Y \leftarrow X$ where $X$ is a topological space, $f$ is *unimodal* iff $\mathrm{lev}_f$ is
>   homeomorphic to a connected subset of $\mathbb{R}.$

This assumes that we've chosen a topology on $\mathrm{lev}_f,$ of course; the most sensible choice seems to be that it is the [final topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_topology) induced by $f_0$.

Anyway, I have a bunch of questions about all this.

> **Questions.**
>
> **Q0.** Are levelsets/levelspaces (as defined above) used anywhere in e.g. optimization theory, probability theory, or "hard" analysis? If so, what is the accepted terminology regarding these things, and where can I learn more?
>
> **Q1.** Under reasonable hypotheses, does the above definition of "unimodal" agree with what appears to be the [standard definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unimodality)?
>
> I quote from the wikipedia page:
>
> "A more general definition, applicable to a function $f(X)$ of a vector variable $X$ is that $f$ is unimodal if there is a one to one differentiable mapping $X = G(Z)$ such that $f(G(Z))$ is convex. Usually one would want $G(Z)$ to be continuously differentiable with nonsingular Jacobian matrix."
>
> **Q2.** Assuming $Y$ carries topological structure and $f : Y \leftarrow X$ is continuous, does it follow that $f_1$ is continuous?

I included "algebraic geometry" in the tags in the hope that someone in that community might know more about this, despite that these questions obviously doesn't fit that tag directly. Also, the main thing I wanted to ask is Q0. The other two questions should be treated as bonus questions, therefore posts that attempt to answer (with at least moderate levels of success) either/both of Q1/Q2 will be awarded a small bounty.

Comment: If $f$ is a proper smooth submersion $M \to N$ then the partition into level sets is the simplest kind of folitation $\mathcal F$ on $M$; the quotient space one gets by identifying the leaves (your levelspace) is $N$. (These are, for that reason, called simple foliations). Then much of foliation theory is doing one's best to pretend one's studying simple foliations. (For a general foliation $M/\mathcal F$ needn't be anything even moderately reasonable.)

Comment: @MikeMiller, thanks. Looks like I need to read up on these foliation thingys. Do you know if they provide anything like an answer to [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1409233/what-theorems-or-frameworks-explain-why-the-roots-of-well-behaved-functions-h) old question of mine?

Comment: In a foliation you partition a bigger manifold into disjoint submanifolds. In particular the non-manifold pieces in your question there can't occur in a foliation.

Comment: @MikeMiller, how sad...

Comment: Are you sure this does what you want in one dimension?  If I have your definition, the levelspace of the normal distribution with mean 0 and variance 1, $N(0,1)$ is the same as the levelspace of the bimodal $N(-1,1) + N(1,1)$, i.e., every levelset is a singleton.

Comment: @EricTowers, dude, good point. The definition seems to fall apart in the one-dimensional case. Perhaps levelsets are best defined as certain connected subsets of $Y \times X$. I'll have to ponder it some more.

Comment: https://www.math.upenn.edu/~ghrist/preprints/unimodalsnote.pdf